# Wordpress 404 error when adding /?name=someonesname at the end of my URL

Tags: wordpress, url-parameters, aweber

I am **trying to pass informations from aweber to my thank you page**, but for some reasons, only the name parameter doesn't work, it makes a 404 error.

Every other URL parameters works perfectly ( for exemple ?email=yourmail&birthday=02/05/1982 ) but the name makes this 404 error.

This problem was occuring on my landing page so i decided to try on the root url ( www.mydomain.com/?name=paul ) and it makes a 404 error also..

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

`name` is a reserved term, you cant use it, try another variation

https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I don't know what to do because i can't control the variation's name, it's aweber that does everything, i will contact them to see what can i do.

Comment: this logic is the same if you have a custom post type "download", then you cant use "download" as query string (url parameter)

Comment: This worked for me and I could not find this information anywhere else. Mega props!